Why is the almost sure finiteness of $\{ n \in \mathbb N : \omega \in A_n\}$ equivalent to the Borel-Cantelli lemma?
In my notes, it states the following (verbatim) as the Borel-Cantelli lemma:

Let $(A_n)$ be a sequence of events.
(i) If $\sum_{n \in \mathbb N} \mathbb P(A_n) < \infty $ then $\mathbb P(\limsup A_n) = 0$, or equivalently, $\{ n \in \mathbb N : \omega \in A_n \}$ is almost surely finite.
(ii) If $\sum_{n \in \mathbb N} \mathbb P(A_n) = \infty $ and the events $(A_n)$ are independent then $\mathbb P(\limsup A_n) =  1$, or equivalently, $\{ n \in \mathbb N : \omega \in A_n \}$ is almost surely infinite.

I don't understand how the "or equivalently" follows, or what it even means. Is $\omega$ a fixed element of the probability space $\Omega$? I get that
$$ \omega \in \limsup_n A_n \iff \{n\in \mathbb N : \omega \in A_n\}\text{ is infinite }$$
but I don't understand how the equivalence follows. Is it meant to say "for all $\omega \in \Omega$" or something similar?

In $(i)$ it means that if you pick a random $\omega\in\Omega$ then with probability $1$ this element belongs only to finitely many of the $A_n$.

@Mark So it means "for almost all $\omega$ the set ${ n \in \mathbb N : \omega \in A_n }$ is finite" ? That makes much more sense. If you post an answer, I'll accept it.

In $(i)$ it means that if you pick a random $\omega\in\Omega$ then with probability $1$ this element belongs only to finitely many of the $A_n$. In other words, for almost every $\omega$, the set $\{n\in\mathbb{N}: \omega\in A_n\}$ is finite.

The wording that is used in your nodes is weird:$ \{ n \in \mathbb N : \omega \in A_n \}$ is an event. It isn't usual to talk about events being almost surely finite (or infinite for the second B-C lemma). What it should say is that the random variable defined by $X(\omega) = |\{ n \in \mathbb N : \omega \in A_n \}|$ is almost surely finite (or infinite). (Here by $|A|$, I mean the cardinality of the set $A$, which, for present purposes, I view as a member of the extended reals $\Bbb{R} \cup \{-\infty, +\infty\}$.) It requires a little bit of thought about the formal definitions of the $\limsup$ and $\liminf$ operators for sets to see that the stated equivalences hold (see the Wikipedia page on set-theoretic limits).
